# Why Duplicate Status Uploaded in Kendo Upload ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

[image: Dplicate status uploaded "done"]

I have kendo upload code like this

```
$("#ku_upload").kendoUpload({
  async: {
    saveUrl: "save",
    removeUrl: function (e) {
      //$(".k-upload-files.k-reset").find("li").remove();
    },
    autoUpload: false,
  },
  validation: {
    allowedExtensions: [".pdf", ".jpg", ".JPG", ".png", ".xls", ".xlsx"],
    maxFileSize: 5000000,
  },
  multiple: false,
  upload: function (e) {
    var files = e.files;
    $.each(files, function () {
      $("#ku_upload").data("kendoUpload").options.async.saveUrl =
        $("#urlPath").val() + "/Klaim/UploadFile";
    });
  },
  success: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.response.status == false) {
      $(".k-upload-files.k-reset").find("li").remove();
      //alert(e.response.remarks);
      swal.fire({
        title: "Info",
        text: e.response.remarks,
        icon: "success",
        button: "OK",
      });
    } else {
      p_str_fileName = e.response.filename;
      $("#txt_doc_klaim").val(p_str_fileName);
      $("#txt_doc_klaim").change();
    }
  },
  error: function (e) {
    if (e.response.status == false) {
      alert("error, upload gagal");
    }
  },
  remove: function (e) {
    $(".k-upload-files.k-reset").find("li").remove();
  },
  select: function (e) {
    var notAllowed = false;
    $.each(e.files, function (index, value) {
      var i_str_extension = [".pdf", ".jpg", ".JPG", ".png", ".xls", ".xlsx"];
      if (i_str_extension.includes(value.extension) == false) {
        alert("File yang diizikan .zip, .pdf, .jpg, .JPG, .png, .xls, .xlsx");
        notAllowed = true;
      }
    });
    var breakPoint = 0;
    if (notAllowed == true) e.preventDefault();
  },
});
```

I want to write a code which doesn't duplicate the uploaded status when I upload more than one file.